# A really tough riley-riddle

Tags: riddle

Here comes (I think) a really tough one:

> My prefix is interior,
> My suffix is a neu found land.
> My infix is in a problem,
> I really am early

Can you solve this with $0$ hints?

Comment: @riskymysteries Not necessarily true - there are plenty of Riley riddles in the more chronological prefix-infix-suffix format. It's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: "self-discovery", the minus sign is in problems, no idea about early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> dawn

My prefix is interior,

> daw -- [DAW Interior – Interior Architecture Design Firm](https://dawinterior.com/)

My suffix is a neu found land,

> wn -- neu should be new, giving a clue that there should be a w

My infix is in a problem.

> aw -- A sound you make when facing a problem.

I really am early

> dawn -- The first appearance of light in the sky before sunrise.

Comment: Nice answer. But it was not what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> first

My prefix is interior,

> fi -- [Fi Interiors | The Best Interior Designers Company in Bangalore](https://fiinteriors.com/)

My suffix is a neu found land.

> st -- There are [streets named nue](https://www.mapquest.com/canada/on/ottawa/k1s-3k5/99-norman-st-nue-45.399617,-75.710213), streets are land.

My infix is in a problem,

> irs -- Abbreviation for [Internal Revenue Service](https://www.irs.gov/). Taxes, fees, etc gives you problems.

I really am early

> first -- The first is the earliest.

Comment: I'd recommend adding this under your other answer rather than creating a whole new one as a 'second guess:' edit

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I've seen plenty of users do this, is it not normal?

Comment: Generally not for riddles where the first answer has been confirmed to be wrong, but it's your choice!. Also on another note, I highly doubt any of these clues will give a company. It's very easy to find some random company called X that does Y, so unless they are a big firm I would imagine that this is wrong, and I also recommend for future to try and avoid using them (unless it fits perfectly)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I assumed that the reason the title had really tough, because there are words that are uncommon.

Comment: I think its more tough as the clues are vague. It will still probably contain reasonably common words

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I see...